# How to get the asynchronous method name in the extension method from where the extension method is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, extension-methods

How to get the asynchronous method name in the extension method from where the extension method is called?

I have some async methods like this:

```cs
async Task ProcessUnchangedElementsAsync(ob1, ob2, ob3)
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```

And extension method for these asynchronous methods like this:

```cs
public static async Task Log(this Task task, List<scanPerformanceLogDto> scanPerformanceLogs)
{
    await task;
    scanPerformanceLogs.Add(new scanPerformanceLogDto()
    {
        Area = {HERE SHOULD BE THE METHOD NAME}
        Time = DateTime.UtcNow
    });
}
```

And I use this extension method to track the time after the method completed execution, like this:

```cs
await ProcessUnchangedElementsAsync(ob1, ob2, ob3).Log(scanPerformanceLogs);
```

It works fine, except that I need the name "ProcessUnchangedElementsAsync" in the extension method. How to do that?

Comment: You don't. Your extension method is on `Task`, which carries no information on how that `Task` was created. The `CallerMemberName` attribute can be used to get the name of the calling method, which could be made to work with some rearranging, but not with your current setup.

Comment: who states the task was created using any of your methods at all? What if I'd used `Task.Run(...).Log()` for instance? The point about extension-methods is that they extebd a **type**, not a specific **member**.

Comment: As Jeroen Mostert said, you don't. I try to use `StackTrace` to get method info, But it seems can't get the expected result in your setup